# New column based on last time row value equals some numbers in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe sorted in descending order date that records the Rank of students in class and the predicted score.

```
Date        Student_ID  Rank    Predicted_Score
4/7/2021    33          2       87
13/6/2021   33          4       88
31/3/2021   33          7       88
28/2/2021   33          2       86
14/2/2021   33          10      86
31/1/2021   33          8       86
23/12/2020  33          1       81
8/11/2020   33          3       80
21/10/2020  33          3       80
23/9/2020   33          4       80
20/5/2020   33          3       80
29/4/2020   33          4       80
15/4/2020   33          2       79
26/2/2020   33          3       79
12/2/2020   33          5       79
29/1/2020   33          1       70
```

I want to create a column called `Recent_Predicted_Score` that record the last predicted_score where that student actually ranks top 3. So the desired outcome looks like

```
Date        Student_ID  Rank    Predicted_Score    Recent_Predicted_Score
4/7/2021    33          2       87                 86
13/6/2021   33          4       88                 86
31/3/2021   33          7       88                 86
28/2/2021   33          2       86                 81
14/2/2021   33          10      86                 81
31/1/2021   33          8       86                 81
23/12/2020  33          1       81                 80
8/11/2020   33          3       80                 80
21/10/2020  33          3       80                 80
23/9/2020   33          4       80                 80
20/5/2020   33          3       80                 79
29/4/2020   33          4       80                 79
15/4/2020   33          2       79                 79
26/2/2020   33          3       79                 70
12/2/2020   33          5       79                 70
29/1/2020   33          1       70
```

Here's what I have tried but it doesn't quite work, not sure if I am on the right track:

```
df.sort_values(by = ['Student_ID', 'Date'], ascending = [True, False], inplace = True)
lp1 = df['Predicted_Score'].where(df['Rank'].isin([1,2,3])).groupby(df['Student_ID']).bfill()
lp2 = df.groupby(['Student_ID', 'Rank'])['Predicted_Score'].shift(-1)
df = df.assign(Recent_Predicted_Score=lp1.mask(df['Rank'].isin([1,2,3]), lp2))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.sort_values(['Student_ID', 'Date'])

df['Recent_Predicted_Score'] = np.where(df['Rank'].isin([1, 2, 3]), df['Predicted_Score'], np.nan)
df['Recent_Predicted_Score'] = df.groupby('Student_ID', group_keys=False)['Recent_Predicted_Score'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().shift().fillna(''))

df = df.sort_values(['Student_ID', 'Date'], ascending = [True, False])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
         Date  Student_ID  Rank  Predicted_Score Recent_Predicted_Score
0  2021-07-04          33     2               87                   86.0
1  2021-06-13          33     4               88                   86.0
2  2021-03-31          33     7               88                   86.0
3  2021-02-28          33     2               86                   81.0
4  2021-02-14          33    10               86                   81.0
5  2021-01-31          33     8               86                   81.0
6  2020-12-23          33     1               81                   80.0
7  2020-11-08          33     3               80                   80.0
8  2020-10-21          33     3               80                   80.0
9  2020-09-23          33     4               80                   80.0
10 2020-05-20          33     3               80                   79.0
11 2020-04-29          33     4               80                   79.0
12 2020-04-15          33     2               79                   79.0
13 2020-02-26          33     3               79                   70.0
14 2020-02-12          33     5               79                   70.0
15 2020-01-29          33     1               70
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume:

- there may be more than one unique `Student_ID`
- the rows are ordered by descending `Date` as indicated by OP, but may not be ordered by `Student_ID`
- we want to preserve the index of the original dataframe

Subject to these assumptions, here's a way to do what your question asks:

```py
df['Recent_Predicted_Score'] = df.loc[df.Rank <= 3, 'Predicted_Score']
df['Recent_Predicted_Score'] = ( df
    .groupby('Student_ID', sort=False)
    .apply(lambda group: group.shift(-1).bfill())
    ['Recent_Predicted_Score'] )
```

Explanation:

- create a new column `Recent_Predicted_Score` containing the `PredictedScore` where `Rank` is in the top 3 and NaN otherwise
- use `groupby()` on `Student_ID` with the `sort` argument set to False for better performance (note that `groupby()` preserves the order of rows within each group, specifically, not influencing the existing descending order by `Date`)
- within each group, do `shift(-1)` and `bfill()` to get the desired result for `Recent_Predicted_Score`.

---

Sample input (with two distinct `Student_ID` values):

```
         Date  Student_ID  Rank  Predicted_Score
0  2021-07-04          33     2               87
1  2021-07-04          66     2               87
2  2021-06-13          33     4               88
3  2021-06-13          66     4               88
4  2021-03-31          33     7               88
5  2021-03-31          66     7               88
6  2021-02-28          33     2               86
7  2021-02-28          66     2               86
8  2021-02-14          33    10               86
9  2021-02-14          66    10               86
10 2021-01-31          33     8               86
11 2021-01-31          66     8               86
12 2020-12-23          33     1               81
13 2020-12-23          66     1               81
14 2020-11-08          33     3               80
15 2020-11-08          66     3               80
16 2020-10-21          33     3               80
17 2020-10-21          66     3               80
18 2020-09-23          33     4               80
19 2020-09-23          66     4               80
20 2020-05-20          33     3               80
21 2020-05-20          66     3               80
22 2020-04-29          33     4               80
23 2020-04-29          66     4               80
24 2020-04-15          33     2               79
25 2020-04-15          66     2               79
26 2020-02-26          33     3               79
27 2020-02-26          66     3               79
28 2020-02-12          33     5               79
29 2020-02-12          66     5               79
30 2020-01-29          33     1               70
31 2020-01-29          66     1               70
```

Output:

```
         Date  Student_ID  Rank  Predicted_Score  Recent_Predicted_Score
0  2021-07-04          33     2               87                    86.0
1  2021-07-04          66     2               87                    86.0
2  2021-06-13          33     4               88                    86.0
3  2021-06-13          66     4               88                    86.0
4  2021-03-31          33     7               88                    86.0
5  2021-03-31          66     7               88                    86.0
6  2021-02-28          33     2               86                    81.0
7  2021-02-28          66     2               86                    81.0
8  2021-02-14          33    10               86                    81.0
9  2021-02-14          66    10               86                    81.0
10 2021-01-31          33     8               86                    81.0
11 2021-01-31          66     8               86                    81.0
12 2020-12-23          33     1               81                    80.0
13 2020-12-23          66     1               81                    80.0
14 2020-11-08          33     3               80                    80.0
15 2020-11-08          66     3               80                    80.0
16 2020-10-21          33     3               80                    80.0
17 2020-10-21          66     3               80                    80.0
18 2020-09-23          33     4               80                    80.0
19 2020-09-23          66     4               80                    80.0
20 2020-05-20          33     3               80                    79.0
21 2020-05-20          66     3               80                    79.0
22 2020-04-29          33     4               80                    79.0
23 2020-04-29          66     4               80                    79.0
24 2020-04-15          33     2               79                    79.0
25 2020-04-15          66     2               79                    79.0
26 2020-02-26          33     3               79                    70.0
27 2020-02-26          66     3               79                    70.0
28 2020-02-12          33     5               79                    70.0
29 2020-02-12          66     5               79                    70.0
30 2020-01-29          33     1               70                     NaN
31 2020-01-29          66     1               70                     NaN
```

Output sorted by `Student_ID, Date` for easier inspection:

```
         Date  Student_ID  Rank  Predicted_Score  Recent_Predicted_Score
0  2021-07-04          33     2               87                    86.0
2  2021-06-13          33     4               88                    86.0
4  2021-03-31          33     7               88                    86.0
6  2021-02-28          33     2               86                    81.0
8  2021-02-14          33    10               86                    81.0
10 2021-01-31          33     8               86                    81.0
12 2020-12-23          33     1               81                    80.0
14 2020-11-08          33     3               80                    80.0
16 2020-10-21          33     3               80                    80.0
18 2020-09-23          33     4               80                    80.0
20 2020-05-20          33     3               80                    79.0
22 2020-04-29          33     4               80                    79.0
24 2020-04-15          33     2               79                    79.0
26 2020-02-26          33     3               79                    70.0
28 2020-02-12          33     5               79                    70.0
30 2020-01-29          33     1               70                     NaN
1  2021-07-04          66     2               87                    86.0
3  2021-06-13          66     4               88                    86.0
5  2021-03-31          66     7               88                    86.0
7  2021-02-28          66     2               86                    81.0
9  2021-02-14          66    10               86                    81.0
11 2021-01-31          66     8               86                    81.0
13 2020-12-23          66     1               81                    80.0
15 2020-11-08          66     3               80                    80.0
17 2020-10-21          66     3               80                    80.0
19 2020-09-23          66     4               80                    80.0
21 2020-05-20          66     3               80                    79.0
23 2020-04-29          66     4               80                    79.0
25 2020-04-15          66     2               79                    79.0
27 2020-02-26          66     3               79                    70.0
29 2020-02-12          66     5               79                    70.0
31 2020-01-29          66     1               70                     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Mask the scores where rank is greater than 3 then group the masked column by Student_ID and backward fill to propagate the last predicted score

```
c = 'Recent_Predicted_Score'
df[c] = df['Predicted_Score'].mask(df['Rank'].gt(3))
df[c] = df.groupby('Student_ID')[c].apply(lambda s: s.shift(-1).bfill())
```

Result

```
          Date  Student_ID  Rank  Predicted_Score  Recent_Predicted_Score
0     4/7/2021          33     2               87                    86.0
1    13/6/2021          33     4               88                    86.0
2    31/3/2021          33     7               88                    86.0
3    28/2/2021          33     2               86                    81.0
4    14/2/2021          33    10               86                    81.0
5    31/1/2021          33     8               86                    81.0
6   23/12/2020          33     1               81                    80.0
7    8/11/2020          33     3               80                    80.0
8   21/10/2020          33     3               80                    80.0
9    23/9/2020          33     4               80                    80.0
10   20/5/2020          33     3               80                    79.0
11   29/4/2020          33     4               80                    79.0
12   15/4/2020          33     2               79                    79.0
13   26/2/2020          33     3               79                    70.0
14   12/2/2020          33     5               79                    70.0
15   29/1/2020          33     1               70                     NaN
```

Note: Make sure your dataframe is sorted on Date in descending order.